# Передача шага цикла в генератор

Tags: php

```
<?php
function Gener($start, $to, $step=1)
{
    for ($i=$start;$i<=$to;$i++)
    {
        $step = yield $i;
    }
}
$generator = Gener(1,100);
$generator->send(3);
foreach ($generator as $value) 
echo $value.'; ';
?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как через send() передать значение шага в цикл, с которым он будет выводить значения

Comment: может создать класс gener, у которого будет метод send() >Это судя по вызову вашему. А вообще у вас есть же аргументы есть `function Gener($start, $to, $step=1)` ну вот так и вызывайте функцию `$generator = Gener(1,100,3);`

Comment: В том-то и суть задания, чтобы сделать это через send()

Comment: Ну сделайте класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае у вас ничего не получится без асинхронности, т.к. сначала выполняется функция и результат присваивается переменной generator, а затем остальные манипуляции.

Вам нужно создать класс:

```
class Generator()
{

    private $step = 1;
    private $start = 1;
    private $to = 1;

    public function __construct($start, $to){
        $this->start = $start;
        $this->to = $to;
    }

    public function gener(){

        for ($i=$this->start;$i<=$this->to;$i+=$this->step)
        {
            $step = yield $i;
        }
    }

    public function send($step){

        $this->step = $step;
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
$gen = new Generator(1, 100);
$gen->send(3);
$gen->gener();
```